# How to make a dynamic 2D array and store a shuffled array in it

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic, shuffle

I've created a 2D arraylist that has a fixed number or rows and an array that holds numbers 1-4. I'm supposed to shuffle the array and then store that array in the arraylist. However, when I go to print the entire arraylist after, it doesn't match, and it appears, it is taking my last shuffle and printing it for all the rows.

For example, one of my outputs is:

3, 2, 1, 4

1, 2, 4, 3

2, 1, 3, 4

2, 3, 4, 1

---

2, 3, 4, 1

2, 3, 4, 1

2, 3, 4, 1

2, 3, 4, 1

Can someone help me understand my mistake?

```js
package practice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Practice {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Make arraylist for teams
    List < Integer[] > teamMatches = new ArrayList < > ();
    //Array for team numbers
    Integer[] teamNums = new Integer[] {
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      //shuffle array    
      Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(teamNums));
      //add array to arraylist
      teamMatches.add(teamNums);
      //print out
      System.out.println(teamMatches.get(i)[0] + ", " + teamMatches.get(i)[1] + ", " +
        teamMatches.get(i)[2] + ", " + teamMatches.get(i)[3]);

    }
    System.out.println("_____________________________");
    //print out entire match array
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {

      System.out.println(teamMatches.get(n)[0] + ", " + teamMatches.get(n)[1] + ", " +
        teamMatches.get(n)[2] + ", " + teamMatches.get(n)[3]);




    }



  }
```

Comment: Do you just want to shuffle the arrays of array or the elements in each array??? What would be the expected result?

Comment: I only want to shuffle the teamNums array. After that, I want to put the shuffled array into the teamMatches arraylist. My expected result is that the first loop prints out a 4x4 array with each row containing numbers 1-4 in a random order without repeats.

The second loop is just there to check if the shuffled arrays are being stored correctly. If the two printed arrays match, then I know that I'm storing my shuffled array in the correct order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding your teamNums to teamMatches, you are passing the reference (pointer) to the same array (same memory location). Therefore when you print after the for loop you will only get the last known shuffle because that's what the array looks like.

You must declare a new array variable for each iteration of the for loop. 
Try :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Make arraylist for teams
        List < Integer[] > teamMatches = new ArrayList < > ();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            // *create new Array for team numbers
            Integer[] teamNums = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4};

            //shuffle array    
            Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(teamNums));

            //add array to arraylist
            teamMatches.add(teamNums);

            //print out
            System.out.println(
                teamMatches.get(i)[0] + ", " 
                + teamMatches.get(i)[1] + ", "
                + teamMatches.get(i)[2] + ", "
                + teamMatches.get(i)[3]
            );
        }
        System.out.println("_____________________________");

        //print out entire match array
        for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {    
            System.out.println(
                teamMatches.get(n)[0] + ", "
                + teamMatches.get(n)[1] + ", "
                + teamMatches.get(n)[2] + ", "
                + teamMatches.get(n)[3]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright thank you! This solved my issue. Just for my understanding/clarification, before, I was essentially only printing out the last shuffle after the loop because that was the only thing that could be referenced?

Comment: Yes. You were essentially adding the same array (same memory location) to teamMatches. So while each iteration of your for loop was shuffling the array, when you print out the array after the for loop you were printing out only the last shuffle because all your previous shuffles were being overwritten. Please upvote the answer if it helped.

Comment: I've upvoted, but since I don't have enough reputation it does not display publicly. Thank you for all the help!